# Listas encadeadas JAVA

Tags: java

Como inverter uma lista encadeada simples em Java? Por exemplo, eu tenho os seguintes valores: 3 - 2 - 1 e o resultado final terá que ser 1 - 2 - 3.

Obs: sem utilização de funções nativas do Java, como ArrayList.

```
public void inverteLista() {
    Lista atual = new Lista();
    atual.setProx(primeiro);
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
        atual = atual.getProx();
        System.out.println(atual.getValor());
    }
}
```

Este código imprime a lista em ordem normal, entretanto não sei qual a lógica utilizada para inverte-la.

Comment: dê uma lida sobre bubble sort, depois aplique para java, existem exemplos prontos em java na netna net.
esse é o metodo mais facil mas pouco eficiente para grandes listas.

Comment: Como está o algoritmo e a estrutura da lista encadeada simples? A implementação da inversão pode ser dependente disto.

Comment: Se na lista original o próximo de A é B, na lista invertida o próximo de B é A. Se na lista original o próximo do último é `null`, na lista invertida o próximo do primeiro é `null`. Com base nisso, você consegue invertê-la com uma única passada (mas o código é diferente caso você queira modificar a lista original ou caso queira uma nova lista - avise se precisar de ajuda nisso). A propósito, por que você está fazendo `Lista atual = new Lista(); atual.setProx(primeiro);`? Por que não simplesmente `Lista atual = primeiro;`, e passar o `atual = atual.getProx()`  pro final do loop?

Comment: @mgibsonbr obrigado pela explicação e pela dica sobre a lista, eu não tinha pensando nessa lógica e acabei fazendo pelo método mais longo, irei atualizar o código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É muito simples, basta criar uma função recursiva que percorre os elementos da lista onde a chamada recursiva acontece antes de printar os elementos:

```
public void imprimeContrario(Lista l) {
  //verifica se o nó é nulo
  if (l!=null){

      // Se não for, não é o final da lista, então faça uma chamada recursiva
      // passando o próximo elemento como parâmetro
      imprimeContrario(l.getProximo());

      // imprime o elemento após a chamada recursiva ter sido completada
      System.out.println(l.getInfo());
    }
}
```

Exemplo da execução do código:

Lista: [1] -> [2] -> [3] -> [null]

Dessa forma, ao passarmos [1] para a função, as seguintes iterações acontecerão:

imprimeContrario([1])
imprimeContrario([2])
imprimeContrario([3])
imprimeContrario([null])
System.ou.println([3])
System.ou.println([2])
System.ou.println([1])

Output: 3 2 1

Comment: Criando em outro método uma nova lista com os valores e passando como parâmetro para o método imprimeContrario(), ele retorna a mesma ordem da lista, ou seja, 1 2 3.